# xparse: inputenc error from unicode character in package description

Tags: unicode, input-encodings, xparse

I am developing a couple of LaTeX packages for my university. They should be easy to use and widely applicable.
Of course, the packages provide many new macros which I define using `xparse`'s interface e.g., `\NewDocumentCommand{\dof}{}{\ensuremath{n}}`.

Since I cannot know beforehand if the enduser is going to compile using `pdflatex`, `xelatex`, or `lualatex`, I tend to keep my code clean from any typesetting engine-specific packages.
However, I noticed that in my docker image that I am using for CI of the packages (turning my `dtx` into `sty` and the accompanying `pdf`), I cannot create the `sty` or `pdf` files because `xparse` triggers an `inputenc Error`.
Locally on my Windows10 machine and an Ubuntu 18.04 WSL, it works without a problem.

The exact error message is

```
! Package inputenc Error: Unicode character ε (U+03B5)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.
See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.115 ...way, it offers a replacement for LaTeX2ε
                                                  ’s \newcommand
? 
! Emergency stop.
 ...                                              

l.115 ...way, it offers a replacement for LaTeX2ε
                                                  ’s \newcommand
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

I dug a bit into my code trying to find text like `it offers a` but couldn't find any of this text in my source code. After more and more digging deeper, I found out that the line triggering the error is the description of `xparse` on ctan. The packages's description reads

> The package provides a high-level interface for producing document-level commands. In that way, it offers a replacement for LaTeX2ε’s \newcommand macro, with significantly improved functionality.

The culprit is the `ε` inside `LaTeX2ε`. What makes things even more strange to me: I cannot find any source code inside my local texlive2019 installation that contains the lines "it offers a replacement for LaTeX2ε" (did a `grep -ri "it offers a replacement for"` inside of `texlive/2019/texmf-dist/` with no results).

Now, I know that I should be using `\usepackage{fontspec}` (or `\usepacakge[utf8]{inputenc}`) if I want to type unicode characters in source code like e.g., `ε`.
And so I used the `fontspec` package just to check if this fixes my problem, which it does, however, `inputenc` is specific to `pdflatex` and `fontspec` specific to `xelatex` or `lualatex`. So then I'd force anyone wanting to use my packages to use `lualatex` or `xelatex` as typesetting engine.

So, what's going on here? Is it a "bug" inside of `xparse` or am I doing something wrong? I've been using LaTeX for more than 15 years now, and I think I know my way around, in particular when typesetting the same document on different OS like Windows and UNIX.

An MWE to reproduce the error would probably look like this

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\begin{document}
Hello, world.
\end{document}
```

however, it does not reproduce my error. So I'm guessing it has something to do with my package's `dtx` file and the docker image yet I cannot pin point there actual error's origin.

You can find my docker image (TeXlive 2019 on Ubuntu 18.04) here:
https://hub.docker.com/r/philipptempel/docker-ubuntu-tug-texlive/
I also tried with TeXlive 2018 from my docker image with the same error.

You can review my code and the CI's output in my repo:
https://gitlab.com/philipptempel/latex-failure-xparse

My commands to turn a `dtx` into a `sty`:

```
pdflatex --shell-escape package.ins
```

And to turn the `dtx` into a documentation `pdf`:

```
pdflatex --shell-escape file.dtx
makeindex -s gind.ist file.idx
makeindex -s gglo.ist -o file.gls file.glo
pdflatex --shell-escape file.dtx
```

Edit 1:

log file:
https://pastebin.com/SCibevJv

(One of) the `dtx` files in question:
https://gitlab.com/philipptempel/latex-failure-xparse/blob/master/ustutttext.dtx

The corresponding `ins` file:
https://gitlab.com/philipptempel/latex-failure-xparse/blob/master/ustutt.ins

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It seems you are trying to typeset the `xparse` package description somewhere (which is not really typesettable as is: if the `ε` wasn't there, the error would come from the misused `\newcommand` soon after). Can you please show the entire log file?

Comment: That is exactly how I am understanding the error message, too. Yet I am not trying to typeset the `xparse` package description in any way. The line triggering the error cannot even be found anywhere in the LaTeX packages of my local installation.

Compilation just fails as soon as I am adding `\RequirePackage{xparse}` to my `dtx` file (of course wrapped in `%    \begin{macrocode}`.

Here's the log (it's rather lengthy but probably worth it): https://pastebin.com/SCibevJv

Comment: The link to the dtx doesn't work.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer sorry, my bad. Forgotten to make the repository public. It's accessible now.

Comment: The logo is `\LaTeX$_{\varepsilon}$`

Comment: The offending line is in your dtx, in the documentation part, and so naturally gives an error when the dtx is typeset.

Comment: On line `115` of `ustutttext.dtx`, replace `LaTeX2ε’s \newcommand` by `\LaTeXe{}’s \cs{newcommand}`.

Comment: That is quite embarrassing. I was sure to go through my code and make sure that I could actually find the text that caused the error message. However, I didn't find it. So it ended up being a typical `inputenc` error. Fixed my code and now, everything runs as expected on any system.